# sapui5 component-preload.js files problem

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm developing a `sapui5` application. I had in `index.html` one js file, `data.js`, where I have const:

```
    const a = 'x';
```

In index.html, I imported the script:

```
     <scrip src="resources/data.js">
```

In my `onInit()` function of `main.controller.js` I can do this:

```
    var myvar = a; (a is "x")
```

I created successfully component-preload to improve performance.

I delete the import of `data.js` from `index.html`, because I can see in chrome devtool debugger my `const a` defined in `data.js` by this way, in component-preloaded.js `data.js` module:

```
    "mynamespace/resources/data.js":"minify content of data.js";
```

This works! I can use functions of data.js successfully, but in main.controller.js:

```
    var myvar = a;
```

I get an exception, "reference not found, a is not defined," same exception in all consts, vars and objects.

What is the problem? Why is a not defined by this way?

Is it necessary do something more in `component.js` or `manifest.json` to my `const a` have been defined in all my controller's?

Thanks.

Comment: You can simply use the component to define the variable "a". Anything defined in the component can be referred  by all the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

**Through the individual definitions:**

First one, that seems to match your original idea the most is include it by adding it to the require call of your component / controllers / custom controls. You'll probably have to return an object instead of simply declaring the variables though, since it avoids global scope.

```
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
  "mynamespace/resources/data"
], function(UIComponent, myData) {
  "use strict";

  //use the content of myData any way you like
  return UIComponent.extend("mynamespace.Component", {

  };
};
```

I recommend sticking it in a JSON model so you can use it as binding as well. If you want to use a JSON model you have several other options.

The first is to create the JSON model with reference to your file. Generally you'd do this in your component file.

```
new JSONModel("relative/path/to/data")
```

**Through manifest.json**

Two ways, one as a file, one without an additional file

```
"models": {
  "mydata": {
     "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
      "uri": "path/to/data.json",   
   }
}
```

If you don't want to load a separate file through ajax, you can add your predefined data as a model in the manifest as well. Take this snippet:

```
"models": {
  "mydata": {
     "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
      "settings": {
        "myvar": "a"
      }
   }
}
```

That'll create a JSON model containing whatever is inside the `settings` bit, so in this case it'll create a model called `mydata` that has an object with a member called `myvar` with value `a`, meaning you can pick it up using the usual model syntax:

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel('mydata').getProperty('/myvar');
```

.. or use it in your view's bindings

```
"{mydata>/myvar}"
```

I tend to use the last option, as it does not load an extra file, and all apps already have a manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I will do it as you said next time I need global const. Thank you.

To solve what I already had wrong, I have minified and compressed all my js files with problems in a single file, and I call it from the index as it worked with        `data.js`.

```
<script src="/resources/allinone.js"></script>
```

I know this isn't the best practise but translate all my const of all files to json would take me a long time.